# ServiceStack sharing sessions between processes

Tags: servicestack, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a ServiceStack 4 API project and an MVC 5 web project and I'd like them to share the user's session data.

Both projects have been configured to use the same Redis instance as a cache.

My MVC controllers inherit from ServiceStackController.

The session is being created by the API (I can see the return cookies and query Redis for the object by session id).

Where I'm struggling is how the MVC project becomes aware of the session id. Initially I thought ShareCookiesWithBrowser on the JsonServiceClient might do the trick, but it doesn't seem to.

So, I've added Request and Response filters to the JsonServiceClient to add the website's cookies to API requests and also add API response cookies to the websites response cookies. This seems to work in the sense that the API call and web request ss-id and ss-pid cookies match, and the session object is available in Redis. Unfortunately, when I call the UserSession property on the MVC controller (from the ServiceStackController base), a NullReferenceException is thrown.

If anyone could let me know what I'm missing or doing wrong, that'd be much appreciated.

**Update**

Just figured out that the Cache property on the ServiceStackController was null. I guess it is normally property injected by Funq, but we're using SimpleInjector and avoiding property injection.

It would still be nice to know if I have to manually pass the cookies back and forth via the JsonServiceClient. It just seems a bit hacky in something as generally well thought out as ServiceStack - I still can't help but think I'm missing something.

Thanks,

Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the HTTP Service Clients to call ServiceStack services from MVC as you can just call the ServiceStack Services directly with C#. Here are some examples from the new [ServiceStack + MVC test project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/tree/master/src/Mvc) showing how to login:

```
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, string redirect=null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var authService = ResolveService<AuthenticateService>())
            {
                var response = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate
                {
                    provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
                    UserName = userName,
                    Password = password,
                    RememberMe = true,
                });

                // add ASP.NET auth cookie
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);

                return Redirect(string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirect) ? "/" : redirect);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    var session = SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
    return View("Index", session);
}
```

And logging out:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    using (var authService = ResolveService<AuthenticateService>())
    {
        var response = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate {
            provider = AuthenticateService.LogoutAction,
        });

        // add ASP.NET auth cookie
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

You can play with the MVC test project which is deployed at http://mvc.servicestack.net/ - it shows logging in, logging out and accessing ServiceStack's typed Session from MVC.

Also checkout the [Session Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ServiceInterface/SessionServices.cs) in the project which shows how to retrieve, edit and adding custom logic in the Custom UserSession's `OnAuthenticated()` event to copy over non-authenticated session data over into the authenticated Type Session as [described in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25824922/85785).

This project does make use of some of the newer API's added in **v4.0.32+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, but surely ResolveService requires the service to be in the same process. In my case, the ServiceStack API is on a remote server.

Comment: In that case yes for remote services you'll need to use the Service Clients. `ShareCookiesWithBrowser` is only for Silverlight version to be able to re-use browser cookies when making requests from a Silverlight plugin. Here's an example of [transferring the remote Server Cookies back to MVC clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/CustomAuthentication/Default.aspx.cs#L26).